# ng-file-upload uploader inside another uploader

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have a problem with multiple uploader, if I have two uploaders but one inside another, when I drag to the inner one, the outer one is trigged as well

I need to set something on scope when the inner one is with drag active and remove it when it's over

I'm using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: set ngf-stop-propagation="true"

Comment: Yea, I manage to disable (ngf-disabled) it using jQuery to check if the inner uploader is on hover, but it's not the best aproach, I was looking for some way to do that the same way that ngf-drag-over-class works